# What is "testchainid" channel?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I built fabric network using kafka.

I created new "mytestchannel".
When I saw /var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/chains/chains on peer server,
I found that both "mytestchannel" and "testchainid" directories.
Also, I checked kafka topic, I found both "mytestchannel" and "testchainid".

What is "testchainid"?
This channel contains important data?
I mean that if I delete(break) "testchainid" data in Kafka topic, does it affect my entire fabric network?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR - You cannot delete `testchainid`.  It is the system channel.

Assuming you followed the normal `configtxgen` sequence of creating the genesis block first and then doing a create channel transaction, then `testchainid` is actually the system channel (if you don't specify a channel name using the `-channelID` flag when using the  `-outputBlock` flag then the system channel name defaults to `testchainid`).

Comment: Can we get the long version of this answer?  Using the `-channelID` flag on the `configtxgen ... -outputBlock` command leads to a connection error when using `peer channel create`.  It seems that the custom channelID for the orderer system channel leads to some other conflict (possibly a hard-coded reference to `testchainid`).  I'm looking in the fabric code, but haven't tracked down the issue yet...